# Yii2 dataProvider Поле по условию

Tags: yii2, datagridview, gridview

Вообщем у меня есть в dataProvider определенная колонка, мне нужно чтобы по определенному условию она показывалась или не показывалась. Если уточнить то если на странице в одном и продуктов по этому полю есть значение то показывать этот столбик надо, а если нет то ясно что эту колонку надо скрыть. Вопрос возможно ли как-то это сделать?

Comment: Вопрос не совсем ясен. Как связан продукт и dataProvider, если скрыть колонку, то она будет скрыта для всех элементов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Перед созданием grigView пробегаете в цикле все товары из датаПровайдера, которые собираетесь вывести, если хоть в одном нужное поле заполнено, то добавляете это поле в конфиг grigView. Аля:

```
$columns = [
 'id','name','cost'
];
if($hasField) {
    $columns[] = 'someField';
}
echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => $columns,
]);
```

Comment: Это конечно все хорошо, но у меня выдает достаточно странную ошибку при таком способе вывода "Array to string conversion"

Comment: Очевидно, что вы где-то пытаетесь работать с массивом как со строкой. ищите где, в ошибке написанно.